# How to create a click counter that saves data in txt file even when refreshed

Tags: javascript, html, counter, click-counting

I also want the link to actually work; right now just runs the javascript I want it to run that plus go to the webpage. I would like for the data to be saved to a text file. Please Help!
Here is code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<body>
//Would like the link to redirect to webpage too.
<p>
<a href="javascript:countClicks();">Click Here</a> 
</p>
<p id="p2">0</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;
function countClicks() {
 count = count + 1;
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = count;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use AJAX to send the count to a server-side processing script, or for local storage save it to a cookie. Javascript in not really capable of writing it to a file locally, Flash is most commonly used for those types of operations. Java is also used, but carries alot of overhead for such a simple task

Answer (score 0):

Cookies store data locally even when refreshed. If you want to store something simple like a number in the browser, I'd recommend using cookies. Mozilla have got them well documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Cookies.

You'd want to set the cookie after setting the innerHTML, set the value to `count`. Then when the browser is refreshed, or `onLoad()`, read the cookie and set it's value to `count` and it will start off from there.

Despite what you may have heard, cookies are not dangerous, they are just a small file, only a few bytes, with a name, value and expiration date. They are simple to implement but they are not permanent, the user can delete or edit cookies. Hopefully this is what you are looking for.